# On the weighted Hilbert inequality a la Montgomery and Vaughan

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities

The weighted Hilbert inequality estimates the norm of the skew-hermitian matrix
$$B :=\left[ \frac{\delta_m^{1/2} \delta_n^{1/2}}{x_m-x_n} \right]_{m,n}$$
on $\ell_2$, where $x_1,\ldots$ is a finite sequence of distinct real numbers, $B$ has zero diagonals (the same hereafter), and
$$\delta_m := \min\{ |x_m-x_n | : n\neq m\}.$$
For the background, see the reference [1,2,3] and the posts [Does a proof of Selberg's 3.2 inequality exist?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133699/does-a-proof-of-selbergs-3-2-inequality-exist)
and [Schur's proof of Hilbert's inequality: streamlining?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415005/schurs-proof-of-hilberts-inequality-streamlining) .
After the work by Montgomery and Vaughan, Preissmann [1] found a bound
$$\| B \|_{2,2}\le (\frac{\pi^2}{3}+2\|C\|_{2,2})^{1/2}\le 
\pi(1+\frac{2}{3}(\frac{6}{5})^{1/2})^{1/2}\approx 1.32\pi,$$
where $\|\,\cdot\,\|_{p,p}$ denotes the operator norm on $\ell_p$ and
$$C := \left[ \frac{\delta_m^{3/2} \delta_n^{1/2}}{(x_m-x_n)^2} \right]_{m,n}.$$
More precisely, Preissmann [1] estimated
$$\| C \|_{2,2}\le \frac{\pi^2}{3}(1+(\frac{6}{5})^{1/2}).$$
This is not optimal. It is conjectured that $\| B \|_{2,2}\le\pi$.
(However, it is proved in [3] that $\| C\|_{2,2}>\pi^2/3$.)
Actually, combined with an interpolation method (see below), Preissmann's proof can be optimized a bit and give a slightly better bound
$$ \| B \|_{2,2} \le (3\| D\|_{3,3})^{1/2}\le 
(3\pi\|C\|_{2,2})^{1/3}\le \pi(1+(\frac{6}{5})^{1/2})^{1/3}\le 1.28\pi,$$
where
$$D := \left[ \frac{\delta_m^{4/3} \delta_n^{2/3}}{(x_m-x_n)^2} \right]_{m,n}.$$

> Question: Is there a better way of estimating
> the norm $\| D\|_{3,3}$ of $D$ on $\ell_3$?

---

[1]  E. Preissmann, Sur une inegalite de Montgomery--Vaughan. Enseign. Math. 30 (1984), 95--113.

[2]  E. Preissmann and O. Leveque, On generalized weighted Hilbert matrices. Pacific J. Math. 265 (2013), 199--219.

[3] W. Yangjit, On the Montgomery--Vaughan weighted generalization of Hilbert's inequality. arxiv:2203.14950

---

Proof of the above purported inequality. 
From now on $a_{m,n}=\frac{1}{x_m-x_n}$ for $m\neq n$ and $a_{m,m}=0$. 
Note that since $B$ is skew-symmetric, 
$B$ has a pure imaginary eigenvalue $i\mu$ with $|\mu| = \| B\|_{2,2}$.
Let $(u_m)_m$ be the corresponding eigenvector. 
By [2, Lemma 5.(b)], for each $m$, one has
\[
\mu^2|u_m|^2
 = \sum_n a_{m,n}^2 \delta_m \delta_n |u_n|^2
  + 2\sum_n a_{m,n}^2\delta_m^{3/2} \delta_n^{1/2}\Re(\overline{u_m}u_n).
\]
Put $\gamma=1/6$ and $v_m=|u_m|/\delta_m^\gamma$. 
Then for each $m$ 
\begin{align*}
\mu^2v_m^3
 &= \mu^2|u_m|^2\frac{|u_m|}{\delta_m^{3\gamma}}\\
 &=\sum_n a_{m,n}^2\delta_m^{1-2\gamma}\delta_n^{1+2\gamma}
   \frac{|u_m|}{\delta_m^\gamma}\frac{|u_n|^2}{\delta_n^{2\gamma}}
  +2\sum_n a_{m,n}^2\delta_m^{3/2-\gamma}\delta_n^{1/2+\gamma}
   \Re\left(\frac{\overline{u_m}|u_m|}{\delta_m^{2\gamma}}\frac{u_n}{\delta_n^\gamma}\right)\\
 &\le\sum_n a_{m,n}^2 \delta_m^{2/3}\delta_n^{4/3}v_m v_n^2
   +2\sum_n a_{m,n}^2\delta_m^{4/3}\delta_n^{2/3}v_m^2 v_n.
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$\mu^2\sum_m v_m^3\le 3\sum_{m,n} v_m^2 D_{m,n} v_n$$
and 
$$|\mu|\le (3\| D\|_{3,3})^{1/2}.$$
An interpolation inequality tells us 
$$\|\left[ a_{m,n}^2\delta_m^{4/3}\delta_n^{2/3} \right]_{m,n}\|_{3,3}
\le \|\left[ a_{m,n}^2\delta_m \delta_n \right]_{m,n}\|_{\infty,\infty}^{1/3}
\|\left[ a_{m,n}^2\delta_m^{3/2}\delta_n^{1/2} \right]_{m,n}\|_{2,2}^{2/3},$$
or 
equivalently 
$$\| D \|_{3,3}\le (\pi^2/3)^{1/3}\| C \|_{2,2}^{2/3}.$$
Here by [1, Lemma 1] 
$$\|\left[ a_{m,n}^2\delta_m \delta_n \right]_{m,n}\|_{\infty,\infty}
=\max_m\sum_n a_{m,n}^2\delta_m \delta_n \le \frac{\pi^2}{3}.$$

---

A proof of the interpolation inequality by the Holder inequality:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m,n} v_m^2 D_{m,n} v_n
 &= \sum_{m,n}\left(
    \left(a_{m,n}^2\delta_m \delta_n\right)^{1/3}v_m\cdot 
    \left(a_{m,n}^2\delta_m^{3/2} \delta_n^{1/2}\right)^{2/3}v_m v_n \right)\\
 &\le \left(\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n}^2\delta_m \delta_nv_m^3\right)^{1/3}
   \left(\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n}^2\delta_m^{3/2} \delta_n^{1/2} v_m^{3/2} v_n^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}.
\end{align*}
The use of the Holder inequality is not quite optimal, 
but I do not know another way of estimating the norm of operators on $\ell_3$.